# Deploying Python Based AWS Lambda Function Utilizing Oracledb Library Throwing Errors When Importing Layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-oracledb

When deploying a python lambda utilizing a layer, adding the import oracledb statement produces this error. All other imports work within the layer, except oracledb. I've tried researching this, but none of the answers out there have proven to work. Has anyone done this and been able to make this work, and if so, can you share the appropriate detailed steps for us to follow?

{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'base_impl' from partially initialized module 'oracledb' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/python/oracledb/**init**.py)",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "9ca4ebbd-a119-4352-96f3-714cf102f229",
"stackTrace": []
}

I've tried changing the version of python. I've tried utilizing steps I've seen outlined on other sites, which suggest using the Linux based version. So, far nothing has worked.

Comment: I don't know how to make it work with AWS Lambda but I know that error implies that it is unable to load the C extension for some reason. That could be the wrong bits (32-bit vs 64-bit) or some other more obscure reason!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import oracledb is all that is needed to generate the error

Comment: Did you ever figure out what this problem was? I am having the same issue.